# How to write a shell script for "AWS S3 Cp" and wait for completion

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cp

I have a shell script that will download the files from S3 folder, after the download is complete I want to perform certain other actions

How can I write a shell script that will wait for the download to complete and execute the remainder of the script

S3SourcePath=$1
Targetlocation=$2

## Clearing the target location files

rm -frd $Targetlocation/*

## download the files from S3 to Local

aws s3 cp $S3SourcePath $Targetlocation --recursive

cd $Targetlocation

printf '%s\n' "$PWD"/* >upload.csv
printf "%s\n" 1 i "File_or_Folder_Path" . w | ed upload.csv

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What leads you to believe that the shell script will continue executing other statements before the `aws s3 cp` command is complete?

Comment: @mark b Basically I want to add the full location of the download file in a .csv file, which I will then use to upload to box ,my code is as below ` S3SourcePath=$1
Targetlocation=$2

#Clearing the target location files
rm -frd $Targetlocation/*

#download the files from S3 to Local
aws s3 cp $S3SourcePath $Targetlocation --recursive


cd $Targetlocation

printf '%s\n' "$PWD"/* >upload.csv
printf "%s\n" 1 i "File_or_Folder_Path" . w | ed upload.csv `-- sometimes this upload.csv is having all the files downloaded, but sometimes nothing is available

Comment: Apologies, it seems that there is some other issue, I just tried again and the shell script is waiting for the aws s3 cp command to complete